# WebGL shader creation problem

Tags: javascript, shader, webgl

I am trying to make a simple application in WebGl and JavaScript, and while fallowing some tutorials I found on the internet, I came across a strange problem while creating some basic shaders. The function which creates the shader program looks like this :

```
 this.CreateShaderProgram = function(vertexShader, fragmentShader)
  {
    var tmp = this.gl.createProgram();

    var tempVert = this.gl.createShader(this.gl.VERTEX_SHADER);     
    this.gl.shaderSource(tempVert, vertexShader);
    this.gl.compileShader(tempVert);
    if(!this.gl.getShaderParameter(tempVert, this.gl.COMPILE_STATUS)) {
          this.Log("invalid shader : " + vertexShader);
          return null;
    };

    var tempFrag = this.gl.createShader(this.gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER); 
    this.gl.shaderSource(tempFrag, fragmentShader);
    this.gl.compileShader(tempFrag);    
    if(!this.gl.getShaderParameter(tempFrag, this.gl.COMPILE_STATUS)) {
          this.Log("invalid shader : " + fragmentShader);
          return null;
    };

    this.gl.attachShader(tmp, tempVert);
    this.gl.attachShader(tmp, tempFrag);

    return tmp;
  }
```

And the 2 shaders look like :

```
  attribute vec3 aVertexPosition;
  uniform mat4 uMVMatrix;
  uniform mat4 uPMatrix;
  void main(void) {
         gl_Position = uPMatrix * uMVMatrix * vec4(aVertexPosition, 1.0);
  }
  --------------------------------------------  

  #ifdef GL_ES  precision highp float;
  #endif
  void main(void) { 
  gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);  };
```

The strange thing is that the first Vertex Shader compiles successfully, but for for the fragment shader it crashes on the "this.gl.compileShader(tempFrag);" line and I can't figure out why.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This snippet from your code:

```
#ifdef GL_ES  precision highp float;
#endif
```

Should be on separate lines:

```
#ifdef GL_ES
precision highp float;
#endif
```

This is because the shading language uses a preprocessor, much like the [C Preprocessor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor). lines that start with `#` are preprocessor directives, that span the entire line. Whereas the `precision` statement is not; it is just a normal statement in GLSL. Putting them on the same line confuses the preprocessor, because it considers the precision statement as part of its directive.

Zecc's advice to use `getShaderInfoLog` is also invaluable for debugging these kinds of problems.

Comment: Yes... such a beginner mistake. I wrote the whole shader in a single string for now to get it to work faster, but I forgot to include \n where it should have been.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't know why it's not compiling, then change your code like this:

```
this.gl.compileShader(tempFrag);    
if(!this.gl.getShaderParameter(tempFrag, this.gl.COMPILE_STATUS)) {
      this.Log("invalid shader : " + this.gl.getShaderInfoLog(tempFrag));
      return null;
};
```

This should give you more information on what is wrong (possibly the use of `#ifdef`)